# Uploading files with AJAX to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, form-data

I'm seding some data - including files to a php, If i just do it throuh HTML and post it everyting works alright, but not while trying to upload it with Ajax and I wonder why.

```
$scope.aceptar = function() {           
    var form = $('form');           
    var formData = new FormData(form);
    var file_1 = document.getElementById('file_1').files[0];
    var file_2 = document.getElementById('file_2').files[0];
    var file_3 = document.getElementById('file_3').files[0];

    formData.append(file_1.name, file_1);
    formData.append(file_2.name, file_2);
    formData.append(file_3.name, file_3);

    $.ajax({                    
        method: "post",
        url: "http:dsfs43r4.php",                    
        data: formData,
        processData: false,                                 
        async: false,   
        success: function(data) {           
            console.log(data);
        },       
        error: function(data) { 
            alert("error"); 
        }       
    });
 }
```

And in php I only echo $_FILES but I'm getting

```
array(0) {}
```

as an answer on the Chrome console.

**edit:**

If I just do:

```
<form id="theForm"  enctype="multipart/form-data" action="http://ge/_m.php" method="post">      

<button type="submit" ng-click="aceptar()">Aceptar</button>  
</form>
```

I get this $_POST - which is that I'm expecting:

> array(15) {
>     ["Lote"]=>
>     string(8) "tyrrtyrw"
>     ["Kg__muestra"]=>
>     string(0) ""
>     ["Kg__ceb__aprovechable"]=>
>     string(0) ""
>     ["-/50_mm"]=>
>     string(0) ""
>     ["50/60_mm"]=>
>     string(0) ""
>     ["60/75_mm"]=>
>     string(0) ""
>     ["75/90_mm"]=>
>     string(0) ""
>     ["90/+_mm"]=>
>     string(0) ""
>     ["Kg__destrío"]=>
>     string(0) ""
>     ["Kg__podridos"]=>
>     string(0) ""
>     ["Kg__merma"]=>
>     string(0) ""
>     ["Kg__podrido_interno"]=>
>     string(0) ""
>     ["Kg__germinación_int__1/3"]=>
>     string(0) ""
>     ["Kg__germinación_int__2/3"]=>
>     string(0) ""
>     ["Cantidad_en_Kg_"]=>
>     string(0) ""
>   }
>   Hubo un problema al subir los ficheros.

So IDK why doing it through ajax wouldnt give me the same result.

Comment: what is content-type header value of your request? it should be multipart/form-data.

Comment: first thing I noticed is `http:dsfs43r4.php` atleast make it `http://yourdomain.com/dsfs43r4.php` .

Comment: in your PHP file you don't have **$_FILES GLOBAL** in this case,  just **var_dump( $_POST)** to see your data

Comment: @ArtsrunHakobyan Still empty either way.

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu Just en example, my link is alright since I'm getting an aswer - I just edited it.

Comment: @OleksiiDubeniuk I've added header:'multipart/form-data' and mimeType: 'multipart/form-data' and still nonthing.

Comment: @xxxxxxxxxxxxx can you add a fiddle to have an access to current code state please

Comment: @Oleksii Dubeniuk     https://jsfiddle.net/grq6vs79/2/  in the php I just do echo $_POST and I get  array(0) {}

Comment: @Oleksii Dubeniuk I've edited the main post also with info.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I did to enable AJAX Form Uploads, tweak it to suit and it should do the job for you! The element with the file in my example is #evidence

```
                var jform = new FormData();
                jform.append('supply_id',supply_id);
                jform.append('fuel_usage',$('#fuel_usage').val());
                jform.append('cost',$('#cost').val());
                jform.append('currency',$('#currency').val());
                jform.append('reading',$('#reading').val());
                jform.append('data_source',$('#data_source').val());
                jform.append('date_from',$('#date_from').val());
                jform.append('date_to',$('#date_to').val());
                jform.append('evidence',$('#evidence').get(0).files[0]);
                jform.append('comments',$('#comments').val());

                $.ajax({
                    url: '/your-form-processing-page-url-here',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: jform,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    mimeType: 'multipart/form-data',
                    contentType: false,
                    cache: false,
                    processData: false,
                    success: function(data, status, jqXHR){
                        alert('Hooray! All is well.');
                        console.log(data);
                        console.log(status);
                        console.log(jqXHR);

                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR,status,error){
                        // Hopefully we should never reach here
                        console.log(jqXHR);
                        console.log(status);
                        console.log(error);
                    }
                });
```